# Send an Email from Task: Why does the To field picklist sometimes show up?

Tags: email, tasks, activities, send-email

When I click "Send an Email" from an Activity History Related List from a custom object record, sometimes a picklist appears next to the "To" lookup field. Why does it appear when  I select some Contacts and not others?

I have tested this with a few different Contacts from the same Account, and sometimes this picklist shows up; other times it does not.

[image: Task - Send an Email example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom email fields can now be addressed in the Send Email page. It only appears if *at least one custom email field* is populated.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, do you know if this is documented?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=email_send.htm&siteLang=en_US says :"Enter a contact, lead, or person account in the To: field. Only one name can be entered in the To: field. For contacts and leads that have multiple email fields, you can select an email address." But I don't think it specifies when this dropdown appears...

Comment: At least it will be documented on SF StackExchange, now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out...

The picklist contains all email addresses on the selected Contact. If there are multiple, multiple options show up in the picklist to the right of the Contact lookup.

Comment: Almost. It populates if any *custom* email fields are populated, even if the standard email field is not.